# HPDF units for text width and height

Tags: pdf-generation, units-of-measurement

Maybe it's just my head spinning, but there seems to be no documentation on the units of measure for HPDF's `HPDF_Font_TextWidth()` function, nor can I figure it out.

The number I get for a particular text of 7 characters is around 3000. The rendered text seems to be around 80 pixels, which is also returned from `HPDF_Page_TextWidth()`.

`HPDF_Font_TextWidth()` does not know the font size so it must use some other unit. What is it?

And is that the same unit that `HPDF_Font_GetBBox()` returns?

I'm actually trying to put text in the center of a rectangle, and need the width and height of the text in the units of the rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old post but I just stumbled upon it because I had the same issue. As far as I know, looking into the source of `HPDF_Font_GetUnicodeWidth()`, the units that it returns needs to be multiplied by the font size, then divided by 1000 to get the width in `points`, which is what the rest of the PDF coordinate system uses.

```
width = (HPDF_Font_TextWidth() * font_size) / 1000.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

All the following return EM units, which must be divided by 1000 and multiplied by the point size to get points, as stated above:

[image]

The units are relative to the baseline. Descender, BBox left & bottom are negative. The zone between caps Height and ascender is for diacritics.

To calculate the height of a slug of text, compute caps height less descender, or ascender less descender if your text has upper-case diacritics.

Keyword: Haru PDF